# How to aggregate multiple points by two columns and create a LineString / MultiLineString out of them

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table called locations that has these rows:

```
id uuid NOT NULL,
"deviceId" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
"userId" uuid,
"userName" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
"creationDateTime" timestamp with time zone,
shape geometry,
CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Imagine My user register points per hours into this table at `shape` column .When register the time of that point that is registered into table, saved into `creationDateTime` column like this `2018-08-22 00:03:41.649+04:30`.

How can i extract this info :

`each User ---- each day ---- list of geometry(shape column)`
in example:

> User1 in first day has list of geometry points.
>   User1 in seccond day has list of geometry points and so on...

I made this query by mongo for same project:

```
{$project: {
    _id: 0,
    uId : "$UserId",
    dId : "$DeviceId",
    ts :"$CreationDateTime",
    point : "$Point"
    }
 }, 
{$group: {
    _id :{
        did: "$dId",
        day: { $dayOfMonth: "$ts" }
    },
    docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
     }
 },

 {
    $sort:{"_id.day": -1}
 }
```

But how could i do that with postgresql? There is not exist this kind of aggregation on postgre and i am new on postgresql.
This is my query :

```
(Select test1."deviceId",test1."shape", test1."creationDateTime" From   
    (Select * from locations) as test1 Group By test1."deviceId",test1."shape",test1."creationDateTime"
ORDER BY  test1."creationDateTime")
```

This query did not suitable result and i know this query has a problem.
**deviceId** of users frequently repeated with other row.How can i handle it?

At the end i want to create multi-poly-line `per user - per day - multi poly line`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably a million ways to answer this question. Here is one of them:

Considering your table structure ..

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE locations
(id uuid,
deviceId text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
userId uuid,
userName text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
creationDateTime timestamp with time zone,
shape geometry);
```

.. And these sample data ..

```
INSERT INTO locations (userId, creationDateTime, shape) 
VALUES ('d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459',CURRENT_DATE,'POINT(-1.25 51.75)'),
       ('d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459',CURRENT_DATE,'POINT(-1.15 52.96)'),
       ('d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459',CURRENT_DATE,'POINT(-0.13 50.82)'),
       ('d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459',CURRENT_DATE-1,'POINT(-2.22 53.48)'),
       ('d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459',CURRENT_DATE-1,'POINT(-0.11 51.51)');
```

.. you can aggregate the points per user + date and create a `LINESTRING` using [`ST_MakeLine`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT userId, creationDateTime, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(shape))
FROM locations
GROUP BY userId, creationDateTime
ORDER BY  creationDateTime;

                userid                |    creationdatetime    |                    st_astext                    
--------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459 | 2018-08-28 00:00:00+02 | LINESTRING(-2.22 53.48,-0.11 51.51)
 d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459 | 2018-08-29 00:00:00+02 | LINESTRING(-1.25 51.75,-1.15 52.96,-0.13 50.82)
(2 Zeilen)
```

Graphical depiction of user `d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459` at `2018-08-28 00:00:00+02`
[image]

In the same fashion you can create a `MULTIPOINT` using [`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html):

```
SELECT userId, creationDateTime, ST_AsText(ST_Collect(shape))
FROM locations
GROUP BY userId, creationDateTime
ORDER BY  creationDateTime;

                userid                |    creationdatetime    |                    st_astext                    
--------------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------
 d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459 | 2018-08-28 00:00:00+02 | MULTIPOINT(-2.22 53.48,-0.11 51.51)
 d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459 | 2018-08-29 00:00:00+02 | MULTIPOINT(-1.25 51.75,-1.15 52.96,-0.13 50.82)
(2 Zeilen)
```

[image]

**EDIT**- Create a set of `LINESTRINGS` per day for each user (`MULTILINESTRING`) using [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) (aka WITH Clause):

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT userId, creationDateTime, ST_MakeLine(shape) AS shape
  FROM locations
  GROUP BY userId, creationDateTime)
SELECT userId, ST_AsText(ST_Collect(shape))
FROM j
GROUP BY userId

                userid                |                                    st_astext                                     
--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 d1166a84-ab66-11e8-98d0-529269fb1459 | MULTILINESTRING((-2.22 53.48,-0.11 51.51),(-1.25 51.75,-1.15 52.96,-0.13 50.82))
(1
```

[image]

Basically what you have to do is to group the records you need (in this case user and date) and use the aggregate function of your choice, e.g. [`ST_MergeLine`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_LineMerge.html), [`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html), [`ST_Union`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html), [`ST_Multi`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Multi.html), etc..

Comment: How could i create multi poly line for each day of user? @JimJones

Comment: can you add an example of such a `multi poly line`? I'm not familiar with this geometry type

Comment: Imagine MULTIPOINT  is good for me ! Now how could i create it line for each day of each user? @Jim Jones

Comment: I am not expert bit i think https://www.tutorialspoint.com/leafletjs/leafletjs_multi_polyline_and_polygon.htm  @Jim Jones

Comment: the 1st query creates one `linestring` per user for each day amd the 3rd one does the same, but in the end all `linestrings` are aggreated into a single geometry containing a collection of all linestrings (daily aggregated) per user.

Comment: Dude i like you :-) Thanks bro